# Python 2.7: Add 2 list items in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables

I want to be able to add multiple items to my code with a function. But I want to be able to still add one single item, or none. Here is and example.

```
listX = ["a", "b", "c"]

def addList(add):
    if add != "null":
        listX.append(add)

addList("d")
```

Adds d at the end. Simple.

```
print listX

addList("e" + "f")

print listX
```

Now it's ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ef']. **I want it to be ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', f].** Also, I also want to have only one argument for adding an item the (add) one.

How do I do this? Please help. And as always, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your list items are always single characters?

Comment: Pass a list into your function, say `add_list = ["e","f"]`, and use list addition such as: `listX += add_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Function `addList` expects only 1 argument, when you say

```
addList("e" + "f") # it passes it as addList("ef")
```

To solve your problem simply use `*` to get multiple arguments, and `extend` to add to it easily:

```
listX = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def addList(*args):
  listX.extend(args)

addList('d', 'e', 'f')
print (listX)
```

returns:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: What if I have multiple arguments? For example:

Comment: gosh darnit why does it post with enter? For example: def addList(remove, add)

Comment: `*` helps taking multiple arguments, but if you do `addList(remove, *add)`, the first and only argument would be used for remove, and all other would be in add packed, so `addList(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`, here 3 would be the remove variable and all others would be packed to add.

Comment: So, what can I do to have multiple arguments and to be able to add multiple items with one argument?

Comment: using arguments with preceding `*` to handle multiple values with 1 argument, I have it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is breaking down the `'e' + 'f'` thing you have there.

As long as your parameter is an interable, this should work

```
def addList(iterable):
   for item in iterable:
       listX.append(item)
```

Comment: you can simply use `extend` instead of looping so much.

Comment: @SSj.Luffy No. The reason why I loop is to break down the 'e'+'f" thing the OP is showing in his example.